# Dynamics 365fo: How can I open a docuview document attached to a VendTable from a Vendor payment proposal

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-365

I Would like to open documents that were attached to VendTable from Vendor payment proposal (VendPaymProposalEdit Form) using jumpref in the grid column without having to navigate back to the VendTable itself.

I tried using DocuRef::openDocHandling() method from within the Vendor payment proposal screen but it open an empty DocuView Form.

```
[FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(VendPaymProposalEdit, AttachmentCount), FormControlEventType::Clicked)]
public static void AttachmentCount_OnClicked(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)
{
    formrun FormRun;
    DocuRef docuRef;
    Args    args = new Args();

    VendTable vendTable  = sender.formRun().dataSource(formDataSourceStr(VendPaymProposalEdit, VendTable)).cursor();

    if (vendTable.RecId != 0)
    {    
        if (DocuRef::exist(vendTable.dataAreaId, vendTable.TableId, vendTable.RecId))
        {
            DocuRef::openDocHandling(vendTable, sender.formRun());
        }            
    } 
}
```